# Java regex to match 10 digit phone number having spaces in between

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match 
123 6523 8745
1234 65 3212
etc many combinations
The i want the regex to ignore the spaces and count 10 digits in a single line. For example [\d]{10} doesn't ignore the spaces, it will match any contiguous sequence of 10 digits. But here I want to ignore the spaces and consider these 10 digits as a contiguous sequence.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Tried it already, it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: ok try the answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
([\d] *){10}
```

(That's my whole answer but I have to write some more.)

Comment: I guess if you answer a question that people don't like, your answer gets downvoted too, even if it's correct.... pity.....